# PowerShell searching matches over 3 CSVs ... slow execution

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have to find matches over 3 CSVs. It is to find out whether users have AccessRights on PublicFolders in Exchange 2016. For ease of use I have already searched and stored all the needed values in 3 CSVs

1. "PF-Folder_Full.csv": a list of all the Publich Folders (more than 5000)
2. "PF-Mailboxes.csv": a list of all the users (around 50)
3. "PF-Permissions.csv": the result of

   ```
   Get-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $Folder.Identity
   ```

   looped through all the Public Folders (that takes ages)

I have written a script that does the job but even on a fast computer it is extremely slow because it has too loop through all the Public Folders and through all the users and then find a match for both values in the permissions

```
$Folders     = Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Folder_Full.csv" -Encoding Unicode
$Mailboxes   = Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Mailboxes.csv" -Encoding Unicode
$Permissions = Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Permissions.csv" -Encoding Unicode

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
        $Permission = $Permissions | where {
            ($_.Identity -eq $Folder.Identity) -and
            ($_.User -eq $Mailbox.DisplayName)
        }

        if ($Permission) { 
            # some code
        } else {
            # some other code
        }

        Remove-Variable Permission
    }
}
```

Is there a way to speed-up things? Possibly through the use of regular expressions.

I couldn't find any example that allows for extended matches between multiple arrays.

Comment: how many entries in each csv? it may work to store them in hash tables/dictionaries for faster lookup.  Remove-Variable is not needed in your loop, but not a perf issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Kory Gill mentioned in the comments: build two hashtables from the `Identity` and `DisplayName` properties from the first two CSVs:

```
$Folders = @{}
Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Folder_Full.csv" -Encoding Unicode | ForEach-Object {
    $Folders[$_.Identity] = $_
}

$Mailboxes = @{}
Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Mailboxes.csv" -Encoding Unicode | ForEach-Object {
    $Mailboxes[$_.DisplayName] = $_
}
```

Then process the third CSV using these hashtables for lookups:

```
$Permissions = Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Permissions.csv" -Encoding Unicode
foreach ($p in $Permissions) {
    if ($Folders.Contains($p.Identity) -and $Mailboxes.Contains($p.User)) {
        # some code
    } else {
        # some other code
    }
}
```

If you want code run just once per unique identity/user combination you could build a hashtable with the combined identity and mailbox name for filtering:

```
$Folders   = Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Folder_Full.csv" -Encoding Unicode |
             Select-Object -Expand Identity
$Mailboxes = Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Mailboxes.csv" -Encoding Unicode |
             Select-Object -Expand DisplayName

$fltr = @{}
foreach ($f in $Folders) {
    foreach ($m in $Mailboxes) {
        $fltr["$f $m"] = $true
    }
}
```

and then group the records from the third CSV:

```
Import-Csv -Path ".\PF-Permissions.csv" -Encoding Unicode |
    Group-Object Identity, User |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($fltr.Contains($_.Name)) {
            # some code
        } else {
            # some other code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hallo Ansgar, the first alternative of yours works perfectly and very fast. It goes through the almot 120.000 iterations in a couple of minutes.

Comment: The other one puzzles me. I think I understand the first part. But the second one eludes me. Also I suppose the "$._Name" should actually be "$._DisplayName", as there is no ".Name" table in my CSVs

Comment: @AlexanderPoettinger Take a look at the output of `Group-Object Identity, User` (remove the rest of the pipeline after that step to get it displayed), and everything should become clear.